# htaccess to remove exact match of index with no extension

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Seems straight forward, but I'm stuck...  My `.htaccess` looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On

// stop folder access
Options -Indexes

// force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE] 

// 
// make all requests append php ext. ie /page = /page.php
RewriteRule ^([A-Z0-9a-z\-]+)$ $1.php [L,NC,QSA]

// redirect /home to /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(home.php)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com [R=301,L]

// this is where im stuck!!! make index(no file extension) redirect but match exactly so indexn or indexnth wont redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index [NC]
RewriteRule . https://example.com/ [R=301,L]

// make index.php redirect to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(php|html) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/ [R=301,L]

// push all processed requests through index.php just exclude the css|images|js|fonts folders
RewriteRule ^(css|images|js|fonts)($|/) - [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

In a nutshell, It works almost exactly as I want but for some reason it won't match `https://example.com/index` exactly (no file extension). If you put `https://example.com/index{anythingelsehere}` it treats it the same as `https://example.com/index`.

I want to only redirect the exact match of `https://example.com/index`.

Comment: Both problem and solution require heavy use of regex so it is pertinent to use that tag here.

Comment: As per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283057/mod-rewrite-questions-getting-migrated-to-sf) and [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283033/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so) this question is not at all off-topic for SO so close vote is wrong.

Comment: @MrWhite: Thanks for restoring original tags. It is strange folks are removing tags. Also may I bring your attention to these close votes suggesting question doesn't belong to SO. I have added a comment above showing otherwise. This has been discussed again and again and it has been settled already that most of the rewrite rules are created and maintained by developers of the web applications/frameworks.

Comment: A regex like `^/index` matches anything that simply _starts_ with `/index` (followed by anything). _Aside:_ You've used `//` to delimit your comments, however, this is not valid on Apache and will break _horribly_ - did you change this just in your question?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
# stop folder access
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE] 

# redirect index.php to /, /foo.php to /foo, /home.php to /, /index to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\s [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index|home|(\S+?))\.(?:php|html)[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L,NE]

# make all requests append php ext. ie /page = /page.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# push all processed requests through index.php just exclude
# the css|images|js|fonts folders
RewriteRule ^(css|images|js|fonts)($|/) - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```